# Using 16-Bit textures

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0, 16-bit

WP7 textures are supported in the Reach-Profile that WP7 devices falls into.
But XNA converts all my ressources upon adding them to a project to RGBA8, that's insane,
the displays of WP7 devices are 16 Bit!

**Information:** WP7 SDK 7.1 (XNA 4), Visual Studio 2010

**Question part 1:** How can I add a RGB565 texture to a XNA project and what is the correct way to load them inside a game?

**Question part 2:** Is there a reasonable 16 Bit texture format (within Reach) that supports alpha with MORE than 1Bit?

**Question part 3:** Is the normal rendertarget (I think that's what the screenbuffer is?) already 16 bit?

Answer (score 1):

#### Part 1:

change surfaceformat like
*graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;*
(XNA) OR (in Silverlight/XNA Project)
*SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;* //supports 32bit ARGB each color 8bit

#### Part 2:

PNG should work... it supports 8bit (256) and 16Bit alpha channel(65.536 possibilities)